# Add texts and links to fade slider

Tags: jquery, css, text, hyperlink, slider

I'd like to add some text for each image (which fades with it), and make the whole image areas clickable links.

Here is the code:

**html**

```
<div class="slides">    
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slides {
overflow:hidden;
top:0;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:206px;
z-index:920;
border-bottom:white 6px solid;
}

.slides img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.slides img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.slides :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn(2000)
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.slides');
}, 6000); // 6 seconds
});
</script>
```

(BTW I use jquery code though I don't understand it yet.)

Comment: Where should be the position of the text?

Comment: It should be on each image

Comment: What are you trying to do ? A clickable slideshow that redirects you depending on what image you clicked ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do

Comment: Change your jQuery to slide DIV elements instead, with all of your elements inside that div. Use the images as backgrounds of the divs.

Comment: @buschschwick What do you mean? Using only CSS/html and having slide instead of fade?

Comment: @edou777 no, you're animating the IMG element in jQuery, change that to DIV and in your HTML use a DIV container instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div and put the image inside it as has been mentioned.For your text you can add another element inside the div and give it a proper absolute position where you want it to show (just like you did with images).

Then instead of doing the fadein/out on images, we do it on the div containing them.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="bla">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f00/f00" />
        <span>ONE!</span>
    </div>
    ....
```

**CSS:**
change it so it positions where you want the the text to show up.

```
.slides span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.slides .bla:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.slides').children().eq(0).fadeOut(2000)
        .next('.bla')
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slides');
}, 6000); // 6 seconds
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/pvudvabu/1/)

Comment: That works perfectly for the text. For the links I simply add some <a tags around the span elements and it works too. Many thanks!

Comment: Well you can have any structure, you can put the `span` in and `a` tag or just simply replacing it with.

Comment: Yes I actually put the 'img' and the 'span' inside the 'a' to have both linkable.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="slides">    
    <div>
       {your content}
    </div>
    <div>
       {your content}
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slides {
overflow:hidden;
top:0;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:206px;
z-index:920;
border-bottom:white 6px solid;
}

.slides div {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(path/to/your/image) center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.slides div:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.slides :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
                             .next('div')
                             .fadeIn(2000)
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.slides');
}, 6000); // 6 seconds
});
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't fully tested that, but it should work as long as your code you posted earlier worked. We are just changing what element is animating.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes my code works perfectly. I tried yours this but it doesnt. Only the first image appears and then its white. And the image is not clickable.